# MS Word 2010 weird page sizes while editing

Tags: microsoft-word

When editing a new file in word it shows the pages as if they were adapted to the content inside each of them. Is hard to explain so I'll attach a snapshot. In the snapshot are shown 4 pages in 2 columns.

[image: Snapshot]

I don't know is it is a bug that appeared after updating to Windows 10 or if it is some configuration.

How can I get it to show the pages in normal sheet size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to `Page Layout` | `Page Setup` | then in one of the tabs there, press the `Default` option.  This should change the Normal.dot file back to the default settings and that may fix the issue.

Otherwise, you may need to find where the `Normal.dot` file exists on the hard drive, rename it to `Old_normal.dot`, and then open Word and it should build a new one, and that may resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried deleting Normal.dot, but it regenerates it and it is still showing the pages in different sizes as before. But if I use any other template it works properly.

Comment: I tried what is suggested here http://www.urtech.ca/2012/02/solved-how-to-reset-word-2007-2010-2013-settings-without-reinstalling/ and it is working fine now!

Comment: Great, I was just recommending as a first step anyway so I'm glad you resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Under File | Options | Display, check the option "Show white space between pages in Print Layout view" (the first check box from the top)